# TypeError: app.post(...).then is not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, nodemailer

I am having some problems with my API routes in a node App. I switched the 'to' portion of my Nodemailer and now all of a sudden it is giving me problems with the Async in my 'Post' Action.

I keep getting an error mesage: **'TypeError: app.post(...).then is not a function'**

Here is the code:

```
app.post("/api/applicants", function(req, res) {
  db.Applicant.create(req.body);
  res.send('Successfully posted new Applicant');       
  }).then(function(appPost){
      //mail details for nodemailer
      let mailOptions = {
          from: '"noreply@cap.org" <app@cap.org>', // sender address
          to: 'ijvv7dth54f7zp3w@ethereal.email', // list of receivers
          subject: 'Application Submitted', // Subject line
          text: req.body.firstname + ' ' + req.body.last_name + ' just sent you a message!', // plain text body
          html: '<b>'+req.body.first_name+'</b>' + '</br>' +
          ''  + req.body.last_name   + '</br>' + 
          'DOB: ' 
           // html body
      };
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
          if (error) {
              return console.log(error);
          }
          console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
          // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
          console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
          // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@blurdybloop.com>
          // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
      }); 
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've attached a `.then` promise handler to `app.post`. `app.post` is provided by Express and does not return a promise, instead it consumes a handler function.

It looks like you actually intended for your promise to come from db.Applicant.create instead. In this case you will need to take your `.then` promise and put it following the db.Applicant.create like this.

```
app.post("/api/applicants", function(req, res) {
  return db.Applicant.create(req.body).then(function(appPost){
    // Respond to the HTTP request
    res.send('Successfully posted new Applicant');
    res.end(); // Ensure the response is sent before any emailing is attempted

    //mail details for nodemailer
    let mailOptions = {
      from: '"noreply@cap.org" <app@cap.org>', // sender address
      to: 'ijvv7dth54f7zp3w@ethereal.email', // list of receivers
      subject: 'Application Submitted', // Subject line
      text: req.body.firstname + ' ' + req.body.last_name + ' just sent you a message!', // plain text body
      html: '<b>'+req.body.first_name+'</b>' + '</br>' +
      ''  + req.body.last_name   + '</br>' +
      'DOB: '
      // html body
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
      // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
      // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@blurdybloop.com>
      // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
    });
  });
});
```

In this case I'm assuming that `db.Applicant.create` returns a promise, though it is not possible to know for sure without knowing the packages you're using. Also, notice that I added "res.end()" which will close the HTTP response before attempting the email code, this is optional but should ensure the client gets a response before the email is processed. You may, or may not want to do this as well.

Comment: Awesome. Could you explain why it was necessary to use 'return' in front of the db.create ?

Comment: It's not "needed" in this context but lets say you wanted to chain another promise onto this, inside the first .then you would "return" a promise. For example you might do `return db.Applicant.update` once you've sent the email. You would "return" this so you can chain another .then onto the end without nesting the next .then. So I tend to always use "return" because it means that now your req, res func returns a promise. If you wanted to chain that in some way, you could (not that you would here). It's more just a convention really.